# Телеграмм-бот с оплатой через Юкасса. Ограничение на amount?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота, с приёмом платежей через Юкасса. Подключил его с тестовым PAY_TOKEN. Сделал несколько "товаров" с ценой от 49,99 руб. до 1499,99 руб.
Покупка всех товаров работает, кроме самого дешёвого. Опытным путём выяснил, что проблема именно в amount (если amount 49.99 заменить хотя бы на 89.99, то всё работает). В документации не нашёл ничего, что могло бы помочь. Может кто-то сталкивался, в чём проблема?

Кусок кода с проблемным invoice:

```
if count == '5': bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id, 'YaClassTG_Bot', 'После оплаты вам будет доступно 5 решений', 'sol_5',PAY_TOKEN,'rub',[types.LabeledPrice(label='5 решений', amount=4999)],reply_markup=sold_markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждой валюты есть ограничения на amount https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-currencies

Для рублей это 75.71

Comment: Спасибо. Но почему это распространяется только на Юкассу? Со сбером и 49 рублей работает

Comment: Таких подробностей не знаю, возможно из-за разных курсов доллара в разных организациях, так как все ограничения привязаны к доллару